# What does the Work done by the system In First law of thermodynamics actually mean?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics

Does the work done in dQ=dU+dW include just the external work done by the system (on the atmosphere given by pdV), OR does it also include internal work done in a system--be it conservative or non-conservative. An example of such internal work done is the following...take an isolated room with a container,gas and a piston,the piston NOT being frictionless.The gas inside is set to expand initially.Is the internal energy of the whole room the same??is the dW of the sysytem zero?

Comment: Thermodynamics generally doesn't care about internal interactions within constituents of the system. Zemansky 6th edition explicitly states that the only work taken in consideration is the _external_ one

Answer (score 1):

In the equation
$$
dU = dQ + dW,
$$

$dW$ refers to work of external forces done on the system (usually in thermodynamics, the system is considered in the frame where it has zero velocity, and this relation applies in this frame).

When your system is an hermetically closed room with constant volume and immovable walls, external environment forces do zero work on the system, so $dW = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

dW here refers to work done by the system on external world.

When we are in a system, even the non-conservative forces do not waste the energy. Like for example say friction in in the piston. The energy appears to be wasted for us, but if we consider the whole room as a system, the energy never changed, it became heat energy and got absorbed by the system again.

Yes, since the piston expanding did not change anything in the external world, the Work done by the system would be zero.

P.S.

In physics dW refers to work done by the system.
While, In chemistry it refers to work done on the system.
this disparity is due to the change in prespective in each subject.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "*dW here refers to work done by the system on external world.*" Why would positive work done **by** the system increase its internal energy U?

Answer (score 0):

It means *transfer of energy* ***across boundary*** ***of the system*** *in the form of work* (mechanical, electrical or other type).

> take an isolated room with a container,gas and a piston,the piston NOT being frictionless.The gas inside is set to expand initially.Is the internal energy of the whole room the same??is the dW of the sysytem zero?

The process mentioned has nothing to do with transfer of energy across boundary of the system in form of work.

I believe your doubt is answered now.

Comment: Got it, Thanks a lot!